# Javascript/jquery elementos duplicados en select dinamico

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un `select` dinámico al cual le traigo datos desde la base de datos mediante `ajax`. La cuestión es que me los trae perfectamente, pero cuando apreto dos veces en el `select`, se me duplican, repitiéndose los mismos datos.

Lo que pasa es que mi `desplegarCatXSecc` depende de lo que yo selecciono en `DesplegarSecc`, osea que en la primer pasada me funciona bien, pero cuando vuelvo a seleccionar en sección, se duplican.

¿Como se podría solucionar?

```js
//obtengo las secciones
function DesplegarSecc() {
    $("#slcSecciones").html('<option selected disabled>Seleccione una opcion...</option>');
    var dir = "CargoSeccion";
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: api + dir,
        success: function(seccion) {
            var secc = seccion;
            for (var i = 0; i < secc.length; i++) {
                $("#slcSecciones").append("<option selected='" + secc[i] + "'>" + secc[i] + "</option>");
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }

    });
}



//obtengo las categorias
function DesplegarCatXSecc(NombreSeccion) {
    $("#slcCategorias").html('<option selected disabled>Seleccione una opcion...</option>');
    var dir = "CargoCategoria";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: api + dir + "?NombreSeccion=" + NombreSeccion,
        success: function(categorias) {
            var cat = categorias;
            for (var i = 0; i < cat.length; i++) {
                // if(idSeccion == cat[i].idSeccion)
                $("#slcCategorias").append("<option value='" + cat[i] + "' >" + cat[i] + "</option>")
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }

    });
}
```

```html
<!-- SELECT DINAMICO -->
            <div>
                <b>Secci&oacute;n:</b> &nbsp;
                <select id="slcSecciones">
                    <option selected>Seleccione una opcion...</option> 
                </select>
            </div>
            &nbsp; &nbsp;
            <div>
                <b>Categor&iacute;a:</b> &nbsp;
                <select id="slcCategorias">
                        <option selected>Seleccione una opcion...</option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

Comment: Cual de los dos select es al que se le repiten los datos?

Comment: Categoria, porque cuando cambio seccion y ya esta cargada categoria, se duplican

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema que estás experimentando se debe a que cada vez que se llama a la función DesplegarCatXSecc, se están agregando nuevas opciones al select sin eliminar las anteriores. Para solucionarlo, puedes vaciar el select antes de agregar las nuevas opciones.

Puedes intentar a hacer esto:

```
function DesplegarCatXSecc(NombreSeccion) {
var dir = "CargoCategoria";
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: api + dir + "?NombreSeccion=" + NombreSeccion,
    success: function(categorias) {
        var cat = categorias;
        $("#slcCategorias").empty();
        $("#slcCategorias").append('<option selected disabled>Seleccione una opcion...</option>');
        for (var i = 0; i < cat.length; i++) {
            $("#slcCategorias").append("<option value='" + cat[i] + "' >" + cat[i] + "</option>")
        }
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});}
```

Answer (score -1):

Necesitas cambiar el bind de `click` a `change` asi:

```
 $('#slcSecciones').bind('change', function(e) { 
    var valorSeleccionado = $('#slcSecciones option:selected').val(); 
    if (valorSeleccionado != "undefined") { 
        DesplegarCatXSecc(valorSeleccionado); 
    } 
});
```

Comment: Pero está reiniciando el select al entrar a cada función respecitvamente `$("#slcSecciones").html('<option selected disabled>Seleccione una opcion...</option>');`

Comment: Claro pero al estar haciendo eso, me elimina el Seleccione una opcion y eso lo necesito, porque sino me toma el valor de la posicion 0 del select y es lo qu eno quiero

Comment: Como llamas a la funcion `DesplegarCatXSecc()`?

Comment: la llamo cuando le doy click al select de seccion:
  $('#slcSecciones').bind('click', function(e) {
        var valorSeleccionado = $('#slcSecciones option:selected').val();
        if (valorSeleccionado != "undefined") {
            DesplegarCatXSecc(valorSeleccionado);
        }
    });

Comment: Intenta cambiar el bind the `click` a `change`

Comment: @octaviosuarez Exacto debes ejecutar la función cuando se detecte un cambio en el select, no cuando le das click

Comment: no entendi bien, tengo que  limpiar el select, como me has dicho en la respuesta, y tambien cambiar el click por change? Gracias

Comment: Ya edite mi respuesta, solo necesitas cambiar el bind a `change`.

Comment: lo he cambiado como tu me has dicho pero siguen repitiendose los datos, te explico paso a paso lo que hago:
1-selecciono en seccion 
2-selecciono en categoria
3-Le doy al boton que tengo que simplemente me pone lo seleccionado en un textbox
4-Vuelvo para atras a donde estan mis select(quedan cargados con los datos)
5-Vuelvo a apretar categoria y aparecen duplicados

Comment: aclaro que en mi ajax lo deje igual que como estaba, no limpie ningun select, que eso si funcionaba, pero me queda el de posicion 0 selccionado